# Is it possible to view live changes in html/css from page served by Flask?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, flask

I have completed the Python part of a dynamic website and when it is run, it serves the pages, drawing templates out of the default folders of `templates/` and the various css and JavaScript they need from the folder `static/`.

So while the navigation, passwords, forms, functionality of the website now work, I am trying to fix the cosmetic appearance. When it was just static files, I could run Python simple HTTP server and simply make changes in the html or css, refresh the browser, and see live changes. Now that the pages are being served by Flask, that no longer works, which somewhat slows down the time to iterate on the design. I have to stop, restart the server, refresh the browser to view every change.

Is there a way - some kind of command line option or something, which will make flask also let these changes be viewed in real time like with simple server?

Comment: I think you want the highest-voted answer, not the accepted answer

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True` will try that out.

Comment: Yes, it has worked. Also put `app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True` in there to make sure.

Comment: Ok, well this is the first I have heard of flask 'debug mode' but when everything is looking good will probably take those two lines out again before deploying on a server.